# How do ASP.net validation controls work?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am confused about client side and server side validation in ASP.net.

I know that client side validations validate on the client side, and `asp.net validation controls` are server side controls. But if I am applying it on any server side control like `<asp:textbox>` and apply `RequiredFieldValidator`, it validates immediately like a client side control. All other asp validation controls validate immediately without post back to server.

So how does it work without posting back to the server?

Answer (score 2):

Even though the ASP.NET server theoretically validate on the server, they will also validate on the client. From [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb52a4x0.aspx):

> If the user is working with a browser that supports dynamic HTML
>   (DHTML), ASP.NET validation controls can perform validation using
>   client script. Because the controls can provide immediate feedback
>   without a round trip to the server, the user experience with the page
>   is enhanced.
>
> Under most circumstances, you do not have to make any
>   changes to your page or to the validation controls to use client-side
>   validation. The controls automatically detect if the browser supports
>   DHTML and perform their checking accordingly. Client-side validation
>   uses the same error display mechanism as server-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTMLHelper in the views it will automatically insert javascript validation from e.g. the DataAnnotation of the model. Things like Required, MaxLength etc. are checked on the client-side (and on the server-side again).